# No entiendo está sintaxis AMD

Tags: javascript

Estoy leyendo un articulo de WebComponents y no entiendo este pedazo del código

```js
//Acá no entiendo
customElements.define("app-element", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<div class="element">AppElement <span>New!</span></div>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<app-element></app-element>

<style>
  /* CSS Global */
  
  app-element {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    background: steelblue;
    color: white;
  }
  
  app-element span {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: small;
    color: gold;
  }
</style>
```

He estado intentando como adaptar ese script a *ECMAScript 6*, pero no entiendo como funciona esto de AMD.

¿Me podrían dar una mano para vislumbrar que es `.define` y como toma el `app-element` sin asignarlo a una variable?

Comment: Hasta donde sé, los [elementos personalizados](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) también son parte de _ECMAScript 6_ y lo que hace ese código es definir una etiqueta personalizada que tendrá contenido por defecto.

Comment: Es correcto. Me refiero a la función. En MDN no entendí bien como funciona ese .define()

Comment: La documentación es bastante clara, ¿ya la leíste?